# Resources for QCD colour factors

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, quantum-chromodynamics

I'm looking for resources on the computation of (I think) very simple Feynman diagrams for QCD processes. The processes are  q'qbar' -> qqbar and gg->qqbar (only at tree level, no loops involved) and my main problem is the computation of the colour factors.

I'm not interested in the absolute value of the cross-section, but in the angular distribution (in terms of cos theta). At least for the gg->qqbar process I think I need the correct factors though, to correctly add the diagrams.

I've already looked into the Quantum Field Theory book by Peskin, but there I only found the final cross-sections but not the calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ALthough I haven't read the book myself, I would recommend [Quantum Chromodynamics by Walter Greiner, Stefan Schramm and Eckart Stein](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540485341). I have gone through another book of the same authors, and they show lots of details in their calculation (i.e. they avoid sentence like: "one can show that blablabla leads to the following equation"). Furthermore, their books have plenty of exercises with detailed answers, so I would *assume* that they have explicit calculations of Feynman diagrams.

P.S. your name suggests that you might be German-speaking, and so you can read the book in its original language.

Comment: @DerKuchen No problem. If you don't like it, then please let me know as I am thinking of buying the book myself at some point in the (long-term) future.